# How to run django migrations when deploying to google app engine from bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to setup pipelines on bitbucket for my django project. I am using the google-app-engine pipe on bitbucket. But I don't exactly know how I can run my migrations to google cloud sql.

Comment: This guy here seems to explain your approach in full detail (https://medium.com/@mrdatainsight/performing-database-migrations-with-django-on-google-app-engine-and-cloud-sql-c7fd298581b4)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue of this is that to run migrations you should be able to connect to your database (even if the DB is in Cloud SQL or an on-premises server).

Let's say you have your DB in Cloud SQL, then you can't know the IP address of the "instance" in bitbucket that will run your steps to whitelist in your Cloud SLQ instance or if you want to use the `Cloud SQL proxy` there is no warranty it will run in the same "instance" as your other steps.

What you can try is to use [**Cloud Build Triggers**](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/create-manage-triggers). You can trigger Cloud Build when you commit to Bitbucket and it will deploy to App Engine. As you are in the same project as, maybe, your DB in Cloud SQL it would be easier for you to run your migrations for your Django App.

You can follow this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories) to know how to deploy to app engine and then check [this](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps) to make your custom build steps.

Comment: but it says "This feature is in a pre-release state and might change or have limited support. For more information, see the product launch stages."

Comment: Yes. It means that some features can change or maybe not but you can try it (Also the support can be limited). If there is somenthing that fails or maybe you have a feature request you can check if there is something already requested [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/5226584) or you can open a new one [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190802&template=0)